# What is the mechanism for the double bond migration in 4-methylcyclopent-2-en-1-one?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds

The problem I was asked to answer:

> Please explain using only enolisation and protonation steps:

[image]

My work so far:

[image]

Seems completely wrong... can someone please correct me?

EDIT I just proposed a new mechanism:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After Step 2, re-protonate alpha to the carbonyl (the double bond has now migrated to the beta-gamma position).  Now enolize the carbonyl - remove the proton next to the methyl group (the top one), then push the electrons all the way back, protonating the gamma position.  Job done!

[image: Mechanism]